# Rust struct with reference to a type with a dynamic parameter

Tags: generics, rust, trait-objects

Here's what I want to do:

```rust
struct Foo<T: Trait> {
  inner: T,
}

struct Bar<'a> {
  foo: &'a Foo<dyn Trait>, // This is pseudo code, I don't think Rust has this feature.
}
```

I want an instance of `Bar` to hold a reference to a `Foo` where the type parameter of `Foo` is dynamic, i.e. over the lifetime of a single `Bar` it may hold different instances of `Foo` with different types for `T`. Since `Bar` only holds a reference, it would still be `Sized`. As far as I can tell this is impossible right now. If this were possible, then I could do it multiple times in the same type, i.e.

```rust
struct Foo<T: Trait, U: Trait> {
  a: T,
  b: U,
}

struct Bar<'a> {
  foo: &'a Foo<dyn Trait, dyn Trait>,
}
```

Now `foo` needs to hold at least three pieces of information: a pointer, a pointer to a vtable for T, and a pointer to a vtable for U. This is unlike references to DSTs as they currently exist in the language, which hold two pieces of information: `&[T]` holds a pointer and a length, and `&dyn Trait` which holds a pointer and a pointer to a vtable. I think this could be feasible, but as far as I'm aware nothing like this exists in Rust at the moment. So, what's the closest thing to what I want to do?

Actually, on second thought, `foo` in the above example could just hold one vtable pointer, and we could have a separate vtable for every combination of `T` and `U`. So maybe this is possible right now??

Comment: "for every combination of `T` and `U`" - this is not something a language will likely be happy to provide, but I think you can emulate that (but not generically).

Answer (score 0):

This is possible actually!

If you compile the first example you get this error:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn Trait + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:8:10
  |
8 |     foo: &'a Foo<dyn Trait>,
  |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn Trait + 'static)`
note: required by a bound in `Foo`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:12
  |
3 | struct Foo<T: Trait> {
  |            ^ required by this bound in `Foo`
help: you could relax the implicit `Sized` bound on `T` if it were used through indirection like `&T` or `Box<T>`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:12
  |
3 | struct Foo<T: Trait> {
  |            ^ this could be changed to `T: ?Sized`...
4 |     inner: T,
  |            - ...if indirection were used here: `Box<T>`
```

It somewhat hints that you can relax the implicit `Sized` bound by using `?Sized`, and doing so will make the `Foo<dyn Trait>` declaration compile!

```
struct Foo<T: Trait + ?Sized> {
    inner: T,
}
```

However, your intuition is correct that this cannot extend beyond a single dynamically-sized field. If you were to try the same trick on the second example, you'd get an error:

```
struct Foo<T: Trait + ?Sized, U: Trait + ?Sized> {
  a: T,
  b: U,
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `T` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/lib.rs:4:6
  |
3 | struct Foo<T: Trait + ?Sized, U: Trait + ?Sized> {
  |            - this type parameter needs to be `std::marker::Sized`
4 |   a: T,
  |      ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = note: only the last field of a struct may have a dynamically sized type
  = help: change the field's type to have a statically known size
help: consider removing the `?Sized` bound to make the type parameter `Sized`
  |
3 - struct Foo<T: Trait + ?Sized, U: Trait + ?Sized> {
3 + struct Foo<T: Trait, U: Trait + ?Sized> {
  | 
help: borrowed types always have a statically known size
  |
4 |   a: &T,
  |      +
help: the `Box` type always has a statically known size and allocates its contents in the heap
  |
4 |   a: Box<T>,
  |      ++++ +
```

Emphasis on the *"only the last field of a struct may have a dynamically sized type"* which gives an indication of how dynamically-sized types are implemented by the compiler.

> Actually, on second thought, `foo` in the above example could just hold one vtable pointer, and we could have a separate vtable for every combination of `T` and `U`. So maybe this is possible right now??

Unfortunately no, this is not supported.

Dynamically-sized types aren't particularly well supported and thus their current implementation is simplistic. For example, you can't actually *construct* a `Foo<dyn Trait>` directly, you can only create one by first creating a `Foo<T>` and *coercing* it into a `Foo<dyn Trait>`. And of course, in that scenario `Foo` itself becomes a DST and thus can only be used behind some kind of indirection (reference, `Box`, `Rc`, etc.).

See also:

- [Rust Reference: Dynamically Sized Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/dynamically-sized-types.html)
- [Rustonomicon: Exotic Sizes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html)